# GitLab Runner in private network

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

I have installed a gitlab runner within a protected network.
In short:

- Runner installed on Windows 10 Pro
- Runner registered with Docker
- Docker running (also tried with restart)

Starting my pipeline with the runner, the pipeline starts, but I get this error:

```
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.6 ...
Pulling docker image ruby:2.6 ...
WARNING: Failed to pull image with policy "always": Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers) (manager.go:203:15s)
ERROR: Job failed: failed to pull image "ruby:2.6" with specified policies [always]: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers) (manager.go:203:15s)
```

I then tried setting up the proxy following this [guide](http://wiki.webperfect.ch/index.php?title=GitLab:_Runner_(Windows)).
Result => pipeline blocked, no result and blank screen (runner is not even found in my opinion).

How can I fix this? If the runner was found by gitlab without proxy I don't think this is the problem. But still the pipeline is not executed.

Clarification: connecting the runner to the open network executes the pipeline correctly.

The proxy configuration of this Windows PC looks something like this:

```
netsh winhttp set proxy 194.13X.X.X:9000 bypass-list="10.1XX.X.X/22"

Thank you!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
2 Issues:

1. Set the DNS for docke to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
2. Set the proxy in the Docker Desktop application, according to my proxy settings.

:)